# Converting store app. into universal app. (Windows OS)

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, win-universal-app, windows-10

Is it possible to migrate/convert existing Windows Store app. into Universal app. ? (New Programmer here)

Comment: Yes. https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Developers-Guide-to-Windows-10-Preview/03

Comment: Indeed it's possible, Windows Store apps are ideal for conversion as differences between them and Windows 10 are few with most APIs used

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me present two possible options:

1. If you would like to port your Windows 8.1/Phone 8.1 apps you can use PowerShell script that will convert your current project to UWP. This is not already a part of Visual Studio but under below link you can find how to do it.
   Note that once you convert you project there might be some changes required like using newer API versions or changes in the XAML code.

https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Developers-Guide-to-Windows-10-Preview/03

2. If you would like to convert your Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app to UWP you can use dedicated tool for it called: Mobilize.NET’s Silverlight bridge

Under below link you can find whole instruction:

https://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/blog/Bridging-the-WinPhone-to-UWP-Gap

Here is also link with good explanation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/w8x-to-uwp-porting-to-a-uwp-project